# Cesium.js: prevent interpolation

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I have a huge amount of boxes representing data across the map (similar to polylines in the custom data source sandcastle example).

I am using **addSample** to interpolate color changes and it works as expected. However when I am transforming the box dimensions with a **SampledProperty** the performance breaks down.

Is there a way to prevent interpolation of a **SampledProperty** and rather have discreet values toggled when the time stamp is reached?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Use a [TimeIntervalCollectionProperty](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/TimeIntervalCollectionProperty.html?classFilter=timeinterval) instead of a SampledProperty.  It should yield better performance.